# How to compare the price elasticity of demand from different points by looking at the graph?

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity

Let's say I have a demand curve looks something like this:
[image]

How could I analyze who have the highest or lowest price elasticity of demand?

it seems that the point 1 has highest price or demand? But why? How does the graph tells us that information?

Any helps will be appreicate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general way of determining elasticity from graph, however linear demand function has a property where demand is infinitely elastic at the top and then elasticity monotonously decreases (in range where $p>0$ and $q>0$) and is infinitely inelastic at the bottom.

Hence, in the case above you  can say that $\epsilon_1> \epsilon_2 > \epsilon_3$ (where epsilon denotes elasticity at point $i$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am a little bit confused how could we understand why `infinitely elastic at the top and then elasticity monotonously decreases`? I feel like the elaticity should be all the same on this linear graph since we only looks at percentages changes in quantity v.s percentage changes in price. What am I missing??? Thanks!

Comment: @James elasticity for a general linear demand $D=a-bp$ is given by $\frac{-bp}{a-bp}$ you can plug different numbers into that equation for $p$ and keep parameters of demand $b$ -slope of demand curve and $a$ - y intercept of demand curve constant and you will see that elasticity of linear demand curve is different everywhere.

Comment: Got it and thanks!